# Playframework scala helper for select input with optgroup

Tags: scala, templates, select, playframework, optgroup

Is in playframework scala helper to achive optgroup in input select?

Example:

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/g4ffzvs8/
```

Code:

```
<select style="width:300px" id="source">
               <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
                   <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                   <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
               </optgroup>
               <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
                   <option value="CA">California</option>
                   <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                   <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                   <option value="WA">Washington</option>
               </optgroup>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution:

```
<div class="clearfix @if(MedicalIncidentForm("incidentType.id").hasErrors) {error}">
    <label class="note note-title  note-@if(MedicalIncidentForm("incidentType.id").hasErrors) {error} else {success}" for="incidentType_id">Rodzaj</label>
    <div class="input note note-footer note-@if(MedicalIncidentForm("incidentType.id").hasErrors) {error} else {success}">
        <select name="incidentType.id" onchange="checkSelectedValue(this)">
            <option></option>
            @for(opt <- new IncidentType().getOptionGroups()) {
               <optgroup label="@opt._1">
                    @for(op <- opt._2) {
                        @**
                        <option  value="@op._1">@op._2</option>
                        **@
                        <option value="@op._1" @if(MedicalIncidentForm("incidentType.id").value() == op._1) {selected="selected"}>@op._2</option>
                    }
                </optgroup>
            }
        </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers satisfied me. Created a new version of the select helper that accepts group names:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String, Seq[(String,String)])], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: helper.FieldConstructor, messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)

@helper.input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    @defining( if( htmlArgs.contains('multiple) ) "%s[]".format(name) else name ) { selectName =>
    @defining( field.indexes.nonEmpty && htmlArgs.contains('multiple) match {
        case true => field.indexes.map( i => field("[%s]".format(i)).value ).flatten.toSet
        case _ => field.value.toSet
    }){ selectedValues =>
        <select id="@id" name="@selectName" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)>
            @args.toMap.get('_default).map { defaultValue =>
                <option class="blank" value="">@defaultValue</option>
            }
            @options.map { case (groupName, elements) =>
                <optgroup label="@groupName">
                @elements.map { case (k, v) =>
                    @defining( selectedValues.contains(k) ) { selected =>
                    @defining( args.toMap.get('_disabled).exists { case s: Seq[String] => s.contains(k) }){ disabled =>
                        <option value="@k"@if(selected){ selected="selected"}@if(disabled){ disabled}>@v</option>
                    }
                }
                </optgroup>
            }}
        </select>
    }}
}
```

(Use `lang : play.api.i18n.Lang` instead of `messages: play.api.i18n.Messages` for Play versions prior to 2.4).

You can use this helper this way:

```
@groupSelect(
    form("brand"),
    Seq(
        "Swedish Cars" -> Seq(
            "volvo" -> "Volvo",
            "saab" -> "Saab"
        ),
        "German Cars" -> Seq(
            "mercedes" -> "Mercedes",
            "audi" -> "Audi"
        )
    )
)
```

And it will render this:

```
<select id="brand" name="brand">
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Good job, but unfortunately I am no longer in PlayFramework (switched to GWT) so I can not verify Your's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the select helper in scala : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html

There is no mention of optgroup so I think the answer is no. Anyway, you can create a helper of your own by copying the code and customize it so that it is integrating the optgroups. For example this is my code for my custom input text. I had to removw implicit i18n language because of a bug :

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: views.html.helper.FieldConstructor)

@inputType = @{ args.toMap.get('type).map(_.toString).getOrElse("text") }
@inputClass = @{ args.toMap.get('class).map(_.toString) }

@helper.input(field, args.filter(_._1 != 'type).filter(_._1 != 'class):_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    <input type="@inputType" id="@id" class="form-control @inputClass" name="@name" value="@value" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)/>
}
```

Comment: I looked at the code of the select helper and it looks painfull to custom. Think about inserting the content using javascript or plain html. The "scala helper" way seems boilerplate to me.